# How to check if one out of four strings have been entered?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I am looking for a statement that checks if the input is either: yes, y, no, n.
It should also ignore whether or not there are big or small letters. I have been searching here for a while but couldn't find an answer I understood. Is there a way to add more then just "yes" to the if statement?

```
    String result;
    do {
    System.out.print("Bigger the better");
    result = scanner.nextLine();
        if (!("yes".equals(result))) {
            System.out.println("Invalid answer, try again");
        }
    } while(!result.matches("[A-ZÅÄÖa-zåäö]+"));
```

Comment: You could only check the first letter for 'y' or 'n', but you would allow a lot more words as a valid answer. But this would avoid checking for each single allowed word separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
if (result.matches("(?i)Y(es)?|N(o)?")) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can OR your conditions using double pipes ||, like so:

```
if (result.equals("yes") || result.equals("no") || result.equals("y") || result.equals("n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your result a lower case by:

```
result.toLowerCase()
```

And then you can compare to any of the strings ("yes","no","y","n") by using equals() as you did, and using 'or' (||).

Answer (score 0):

```
result.toLowerCase();

if(result.length()>1 && !result.equals("yes") &&!result.equals("no")){
System.out.println("wrong input");

} else if(result.charAt(0)=='y') {
   System.out.println("good answer");

 }else if(result.charAt(0)=='n') {
   System.out.println("Invalid answer, try again");
}
```

it will check ether the user will type "yes" or plain "y", or "no" or plain "n"

Comment: Well, this would also allow `"york"` and `"new york"` as valid input. Maybe worth to note in the answer, that this solution is not limited to "yes", "y", "no" or "n". Btw: what is `b` in your code?